# Problem with generating XPS documents with images in a WCF class library

Tags: wcf, image, documentation-generation, xps, xpsdocument

I have a Silverlight application which uses a web service in order to create XPS documents. The document templates are created as XAML controls in a WCF class library.

```
public void GenerateXPS()
{
    Type typeofControl = Type.GetType(DOCUMENT_GENERATOR_NAMESPACE + "." + ControlTypeName, true);
    FrameworkElement control = (FrameworkElement)(Activator.CreateInstance(typeofControl));

    control.DataContext = DataContext;

    FixedDocument fixedDoc = new FixedDocument();
    PageContent pageContent = new PageContent();
    FixedPage fixedPage = new FixedPage();

    //Create first page of document
    fixedPage.Children.Add(control);
    ((IAddChild)pageContent).AddChild(fixedPage);
    fixedDoc.Pages.Add(pageContent);
    XpsDocument xpsd = new XpsDocument(OutputFilePath + "\\" + OutputFileName, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
    System.Windows.Xps.XpsDocumentWriter xw = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(xpsd);
    xw.Write(fixedDoc);
    xpsd.Close();

    SaveToDocumentRepository();
}
```

In order to bind the actual data to my document template I set the DataContext property of the control. The problem is that when I look at my XPS, the images (I bind the Source of my Image controls to a string property that represents the URL of my image) are not displayed as if they were not loaded. How can I solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: is that URL valid? If you try to open it in a browser, does it show up?

Answer (score 1):

The binding infrastructure probably needs a push along because you are operating outside the intended use of WPF.

Try adding the following code after setting the datacontext:

```
control.DataContext = DataContext;

// we need to give the binding infrastructure a push as we
// are operating outside of the intended use of WPF
var dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
dispatcher.Invoke(
   DispatcherPriority.SystemIdle,
   new DispatcherOperationCallback(delegate { return null; }),
   null);
```

I cover this and other XPS related stuff in this [blog post](http://www.bradcurtis.com/2010/02/06/document-and-report-generation-using-xaml-wpf-databinding-and-xps/).

Comment: If I have a `UserControl` that renders itself correctly after a specific event (e.g. `myItem.Loaded`), the dispatcher hack does not work! How can I tell it to wait for the event to fire?